# How can I justify and analyze code's running time, is it O(n)?

Tags: python, recursion, time, runtime, time-complexity

How can I justify and analyze the running time of the code with recursive call, is it O(n)?

```
A = [10,8,7,6,5]
def Algorithm(A):
  ai = max(A)             # find largest integer
  i = A.index(ai)
  A[i] = 0
  aj = max(A)             # finding second largest integer 

  A[i] = abs(ai - aj)     # update A[i]
  j = A.index(aj)
  A[j] = 0                # replace the A[j] by 0
  if aj == 0:             # if second largest item equals
    return ai       # to zero return the largest integer
 return Algorithm(A)     # call Algorithm(A) with updated A
```

Comment: Can you give a description of what the function is supposed to do? Is it sorting the list? And it seems like it is greater then `O(n)` because those calls to `max()` and `index()` each take `O(n)` time. So if this recursive call is done `n` times it would be `O(n^2)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's the breakdown of it:

```
def Algorithm(A):
    ai = max(A)             # O(n)
    i = A.index(ai)         # O(n)
    A[i] = 0                # O(1)
    aj = max(A)             # O(n)

    A[i] = abs(ai - aj)     # O(1)
    j = A.index(aj)         # O(n)
    A[j] = 0                # O(1)
    if aj == 0:             # O(1)
        return ai           # O(1)
   return Algorithm(A)      # recursive call, called up to n times recursively
```

The last recursive call is called as long as `max(A)` is not `0`, which is `n` times, in the worst case, if all are positive.

So, everything up to the last line is `O(n)`, and the last line makes everything run n times, so the total of it is `O(n^2)`

Comment: but isn't the question to prove that it is in O(n)? For this, we need to prove that how often the last recursive call is done does not depend on the size of the input.

Comment: +1 However from the analysis I posted, I think you are right with stating `# recursive call, called up to n times recursively`.

Answer (score 1):

At first, I was a bit sceptic whether your algorithm really runs in O(n). Also the following program

```
import timeit, random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

code = """
def Algorithm(A):
    ai = max(A)             # find largest integer
    i = A.index(ai)
    A[i] = 0
    aj = max(A)             # finding second largest integer 

    A[i] = abs(ai - aj)     # update A[i]
    j = A.index(aj)
    A[j] = 0                # replace the A[j] by 0
    if aj == 0:             # if second largest item equals
        return ai       # to zero return the largest integer
    return Algorithm(A)     # call Algorithm(A) with updated A
Algorithm(%s)
"""

x, y = [], []
lst = [random.randint(-1000, 10000)]
for i in range(1000):
    lst.append(random.randint(-1000, 10000))
    time = timeit.timeit(stmt=code % lst, number=10)
    x.append(i)
    y.append(time)

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

measures the running time of the algorithm for different randomly generated lists (and plots this afterwards). The result

[image]

clearly supports a non-linear grow. So said otherwise since the algorithm is in O(n^2) complexity it is not provable that it runs within O(n).